# Unable to set set max_clause_count on ElastiSearch 2.4.5

Tags: magento, elasticsearch

I have set elasticsearch on Magento 2 Enterprise Edition. On trying to load categories page, I get these error:

(Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException): too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024

When I try to update elasticsearch.yaml to **index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10024** as suggested here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html elasticsearch does not start.

I have read that setting maxClauseCount has been deprecated in Elasticsearch 5 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_search_settings. But I am using version 2.4.5

How do I go about setting maxClauseCount?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am facing the same problem :) @Rodgers

Comment: Hi @KeyurShah ensure that there is  2 spaces before line **index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10024** in _elasticsearch.yml_. Not more or less than 2 spaces.

Comment: Thanks @RodgersAndati I will try  :)